# Can we change .gradle path from Users location to project location in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Since I want to build project in Azure DSVM where there is not internet connectivity.
And I wanted to take all gradle dependencies to that machine. And build + run on the DSVM machine.

My project structure as follows
[image]

I wanted my spring gradle to download all dependencies into `.gradle/` directory inside my project.
And link to this location only. So, that I can apply same settings into my target DSVM machine.

I dont have option to download jars from internet inside my DSVM, but I can copy those manually that is possible for me.

What settings I need to apply ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed above issue by adding gradle.properties file inside `USER_HOME/.gradle/`
directory with following values :-

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<IP-Address>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<Port>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<IP-Address>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<Port>
```

The `IP Address` & `Port number` should shared by respective Firewall network.